# Ordenado de datos alfanuméricos imposible con QuerySets de Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

En *Python* Quiero ordenar una lista de ítems en la base de datos, pero desafortunadamente no lo hace de manera correcta. Recuerdo que alguna vez lo he hecho con *cast* en *SQL*, pero no lo puedo lograr con *QuerySets* de *Django*.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Empresas(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

*QuerySet*:

```
s = Empresas.objects.filter(codigo__startswith="B") \
                .extra({'codigo_uint': "CAST(codigo as INTEGER)"}) \
                .order_by('-codigo_uint')

for x in s:
    print x.codigo
```

La lista se ordena de la siguiente manera:

```
B-001
B-999
B-1000
B-897
B-010
B-099
B-100
B-500
B-9999
```

Pero en teoría debería ordenarse de manera correcta como la siguiente:

```
['B-001', 'B-002', 'B-010', 'B-011', 'B-099', 'B-100', 'B-500', 'B-897', 'B-999', 'B-1000', 'B-9999']
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir una columna extra que contenga sólo los números de la columna de código, y después ordenar en base a esta columna.

```
      from django.db.models.functions import Substr
 s=Empresas.objects.filter(codigo__startswith="B").annotate(numeros=Substr('codigo',3)).order_by('numeros')
```

annotate(), sirve para agregar una columna extra al resultado de la consulta. Después, `numeros` es el nombre de esta nueva columna; y para obtener los números de la columna  se usa la función importada `Substr(<nombre de columna>, <inicio>, <final>).`
Dale una leída a la documentación de Django acerca de las funciones dentro de las consultas: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/